# Unknown Date Format to Dec 6, 2015

Tags: jquery, angularjs, api

I have a service that returns todays date as so:

```
1449446389
```

And I am needing it to read:

```
Dec 6, 2015
```

I am trying to do this in AngularJS with the date filter:

```
<td>{{domain.created | date}}</td>
```

But it returns this:

```
Jan 17, 1970
```

I'm not sure what the format of the date above is and I don't know how to format it using AngularJS.

Sorry for the stupid question i'm sure. But please help me. It's incredibly hard to search for a resolution when you don't even know the current or starting format.

Comment: Most serverside languages return POSIX timestamps, or in other words seconds since Thursday, 1 January 1970. Javascript uses milliseconds instead of seconds, so you have to multiple your timestamps by a thousand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try multiplying date by `1000` , using `String.prototype.slice()` to extract only month, day, year ; `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/(\d+)/` to match digits, insert comma after digits at returned string

```js
var t = 1449446389
, date = String(new Date(t * 1000)).slice(4, -24).replace(/(\d+)/, "$1,");
console.log(date)
```

Comment: JavaScript expects the date to be passed as milliseconds, meanwhile the server is returning seconds

Comment: I had tried to using date.toString() as thats what I had found for milliseconds but it didn't work. So I'm guessing you are right. Let me try your code.

Comment: That worked. However, how would you add the , to the date. So it would look like: Dec 06, 2015

Comment: @moevans _"That worked. However, how would you add the , to the date. So it would look like: Dec 06, 2015"_ Could use `.replace()` , see updated post